# What does it mean by "Cannot bind generic curve on Transform component"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

When i try to apply an override to my animation clip. It gives me this warning and stop the program.

"Cannot bind generic curve on Transform component, only position, rotation and scale curve are supported."

```cs
    void CopyAnimationClip()
    {
        Animation_Copy = new AnimationClip();
        for (int i = 0; i < keyframedata.Length; i++)
        {
            AnimationCurve newCurve = new AnimationCurve(keyframedata[i]);
            Animation_Copy.SetCurve(RelativePath[i], typeof(Transform), propertyName[i], newCurve);
        }
        animOverride["BounceAnimation"] = Animation_Copy; //Where the warning comes from
    }
```

And the propertyName here is "LocalPosition.y", "LocalScale.y", "LocalScale.x". And RelativePath is empty (i'm animating the root object).

What feels strange to me is
This only happens when i try to export the animation data to a file and then import it back. When i directly read the animation data from the animation clip and put it back it works fine.(I have another piece of code can read the data from animation clip and store them into the array above). I'm saving the data in plain text. Could that be the problem? (I still feel confused about serialization and deserialization so i didn't use them)

**To DerHugo's question**

Yes there are some difference. Because the property name i read from the animation is "m_LocalePosition.y" and when i use this in the constructor to create the curve (Again, only when i try to load from file), Unity gave me

"Can't assign curve because m_LocalPosition.y
 is not a valid Transform property."

And i checked the API for unity animation, it seems there isn't something like "m_", so have to do this before i write it into the file. I don't need this step when i read it directly from Unity animation clip at runtime.

```cs
 propertyName[i] = propertyName[i].Replace("m_", "");
```

Then i can create the curve and then i get the problem above.

Here is the code i use to read data from the Animation clip

```cs
    void LoadAnimationDataFromEditor()
    {
        //Get the curve binding in the animation.
        UnityEditor.EditorCurveBinding[] curveBindings = UnityEditor.AnimationUtility.GetCurveBindings(InputAnimation);
        //Get the binded curve in the curve binding.
        AnimationCurve[] curves = new AnimationCurve[curveBindings.Length];
        //Create and store the data needed to create a curve
        keyframedata = new Keyframe[curves.Length][];
            //The array to keep the original keyframe value.
        keyframeValues = new float[curves.Length][];
        RelativePath = new string[curves.Length];
        propertyName = new string[curves.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < curves.Length; i++)
        {
            //Store curve data
            RelativePath[i] = curveBindings[i].path;
            propertyName[i] = curveBindings[i].propertyName;
            curves[i] = UnityEditor.AnimationUtility.GetEditorCurve(InputAnimation, curveBindings[i]);

            //Get key frame in each curve
            Keyframe[] keyframes = curves[i].keys;
            //Create an array of keyframes to store the game keyframe data
            keyframedata[i] = new Keyframe[curves[i].keys.Length];
            keyframeValues[i] = new float[curves[i].keys.Length];
            for (int a = 0; a < keyframes.Length; a++)
            {
                //Copy the keyframe data to array for editing test
                keyframedata[i][a] = keyframes[a];
                keyframeValues[i][a] = keyframes[a].value;
            }
        }
    }

//And the code to modify the animation data
    void SliderListener()
    {
        keyframedata[0][0].value = keyframeValues[0][0] + HeightSlider.value;
        keyframedata[0][2].value = keyframeValues[0][2] + HeightSlider.value;
        CopyAnimationClip();
    }

//The code to save animation to file
    void SaveAnimationToFile(string path)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < RelativePath.Length; i++)
        {
            //The animation data file is the file to store animation data like keyframes;
            string animationdatafilepath = path + "/" + RelativePath[i] + "/" + propertyName[i] + ".txt";
            if (File.Exists(animationdatafilepath))
            {
                //If the file already exists, delete and create new one.
                File.Delete(animationdatafilepath);
                Debug.Log("Already have a file with same name, overwrite");
            }
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(animationdatafilepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(RelativePath[i]);//Write the relative path of the transform
                propertyName[i] = propertyName[i].Replace("m_", "");
                sw.WriteLine(propertyName[i]);//Write the property name of the transform
                sw.WriteLine(keyframedata[i].Length);//Write how many keyframes are there in the curve (so when loading the program knows how many to expect)
                for (int c = 0; c < keyframedata[i].Length; c++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(keyframedata[i][c].time.ToString("F7") + ","//Keep 7 decimals, that is almost the maximum accurate for float
                        + keyframedata[i][c].value.ToString("F7") + ","
                        + keyframedata[i][c].inTangent.ToString("F7") + ","
                        + keyframedata[i][c].outTangent.ToString("F7") + ","
                        + keyframedata[i][c].weightedMode + ","
                        + keyframedata[i][c].inWeight.ToString("F7") + ","
                        + keyframedata[i][c].outWeight.ToString("F7"));
                }
            }
            Debug.Log("File has been created at " + animationdatafilepath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "only position, rotation and scale curve are supported" `AnimationCurve` is not one of those.

Comment: But in Unity API "AnimationClip.SetCurve" is used with an AnimationCurve. And when i read the memory for the data and use this code to modify the curve, it works without any error

Comment: That's really strange ... When I implemented and wrote [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852262/7111561) I tested it with only nested `Transform` components animated and it worked for me without a problem

Comment: How do you read/write the file currently? Is it possible there is an additional hidden symbol like a `/r` or `/n` in the string from file? Shouldn't be the case using my binaryformatter solution but you never know ... Can you maybe check if both strings are really equal?

Comment: Hello derHugo. Glad to see you helping here. I have read your code and tried myself, it does work well and helped me a lot when designing this code, but because this is my graduate project so i'm avoiding to copy and paste code directly from yours. And get confused by why it work in different way when exported into a plaintext than byte stream. So maybe i will go for your solution and try to get familize with serialization.