# How do I store Animation Clips in a non-Unity editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Animation Clips is not serialize how to solve?

i was use create other Class be similar to animation clip but "SetCurve" i can't come true i want  runtime save animation Clip.anim in build project!how to solve problems thanks!!!

Comment: Would this (at least partially) answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852262/7111561 This shows how to pre-store the curves information on editor time and how to overwrite the values on runtime (aka import clip info) .. runtime export seems a bit more complex tbh and might require some reflection / assembly bridge for internals

Comment: Consider trying DoTween for animations
http://dotween.demigiant.com/